# Parsing <span> tag and getting data with python

Tags: python, html, parsing

I'm new on stackoverflow and this is my first question.

I'm writing script in Python for parsing HTML page.
Page looks like this:

```
<TABLE style="border: 1px solid black">

<TR>
    <TD colspan="2"><span id="text1" style="color: white">DATA1</span></TD>
</TR>
<TR>    
    <TD class="rowLabel" valign="top">Data name</TD>
    <TD valign="top" width="100"><span id="somename1" class="alsoname">DATA2</span></TD>
</TR>   
<TR>    
    <TD class="rowLabel" valign="top">Data name</TD>
    <TD valign="top" width="100"><span id="somename2" class="alsoname">DATA3</span></TD>
</TR>                                               
<TR>
    <TD class="rowLabel" valign="top">Data name</TD>
    <TD valign="top" width="100"><span id="somename3" class="alsoname">DATA4</span></TD>
</TR>
<TR>
    <TD class="rowLabel" valign="top">Data name</TD>
    <TD valign="top" width="100"><span id="somename4" class="alsoname">DATA5</span></TD>
</TR>
<TR>
    <TD class="rowLabel" valign="top">Data name</TD>
    <TD valign="top" width="100"><span id="somename5" class="alsoname">DATA6</span></TD>
</TR>                                               
<TR>
    <TD class="rowLabel" valign="top">Data name</TD>
    <TD valign="top" width="100"><span id="somename6" class="alsoname">DATA7</span></TD>
</TR>
<TR>
    <TD class="rowLabel" valign="top">Data name</TD>
    <TD valign="top" width="100"><span id="somename7" class="alsoname">DATA8</span></TD>
</TR>
```

I would like to collect DATA values from  brackets based on span id name.
If span ID == somename1 then put it's DATA value in variable.

so far I have this code:

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if tag == 'span':
            for name, value in attrs:
                if name == 'id' and value == 'somename1':
                    print 'ID', value
                elif name == 'id' and value == 'somename2':
                    print 'ID', value
                elif name == 'id' and value == 'somename3':
                    print 'ID', value
                else :
                    print 'NO DATA'

p = MyHTMLParser()
p.feed(flush)
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: If beautifulsoup is an option, then here is the link http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/

Answer (score 2):

I find that using BeautifulSoup with any sort of HTML is much easier.

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup as bs
from urllib2 import urlopen

data = urlopen('wherever').read()

soup = bs(data)

for span in soup.findAll('span'):
    print span['id'], span.text
```

You may have to refine some parts of it, since you only provided a table.

Comment: This seams more easier and I get data printed out but I get some error in the end 'Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "g1.py", line 99, in <module>
    print span['id'], span.text
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/BeautifulSoup.py", line 601, in __getitem__
    return self._getAttrMap()[key]
KeyError: 'id''

Comment: It's possible that another <span> tag is present on the page and one or more of them don't have an 'id' attribute.  Like, I said, you'll have to refine it to match just the table that contains the appropriate <span> tags.

Also, I apologize for the delay, I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Overriding the `handle_starttag` method is not enough. Unfortunately the basic `HTMLParser` is not quite... *usable* in my opinion, maybe you have a look at [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/). You could do it like this:

```
class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        self.collect_data = False
        self.tagname = None
        self.id = None

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if tag == 'span':
            for name, value in attrs:
                if name == 'id' and value == 'somename1':
                    self.collect_data = True
                    self.tagname = tag
                    self.id = value

    def handle_data(self, data):
        if self.collect_data:
            self.somevar = data
            self.collect_data = False

            print "Tag: %s ID: %s" % (self.tagname, self.id)
            print "Data: %s" % data
```

With the `collect_data` we state that we want to put the next data incoming (in the `handle_data` method) into a variable. We turn this boolean on, when `id` is `somename1` and turn it off, when we have collected the data. Not really beautiful, isn't it?

Comment: maybe this could work. how to I print out collected DATA and somename according to DATA?

Comment: I edited my answer, now you also have the information about the tag/id when you access the data.

Comment: uf. this is ugly :) I think I'm going to do it in Beautiful Soup as proposed in letter answer from @kryptn thanks anyway :)

Comment: Yep it is. Thats why I recommended it. Good luck with it :)